# GoogleAPICallError: None Unexpected state: Long-running operation had neither response nor error set

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform and I'm trying to create a Feature Store to fill with values from a csv file from Google Cloud Storage. The aim is to do that from a local notebook in Python.
I'm basically following the code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/master/notebooks/official/feature_store/gapic-feature-store.ipynb), making the appropriate changes since I'm working with the credit card public dataset.
The error that raises when I run the code is the following:

```
GoogleAPICallError: None Unexpected state: Long-running operation had neither response nor error set.
```

and it happens during the ingestion of the data from the csv file.

Here it is the code I'm working on:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types import feature as feature_pb2
from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types import featurestore as featurestore_pb2
from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types import \
    featurestore_service as featurestore_service_pb2
from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types import entity_type as entity_type_pb2
from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types import FeatureSelector, IdMatcher

credential_path = r"C:\Users\...\.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path

## Constants
PROJECT_ID = "my-project-ID"
REGION = "us-central1"
API_ENDPOINT = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
INPUT_CSV_FILE = "my-input-file.csv"
FEATURESTORE_ID = "fraud_detection"

## Output dataset
DESTINATION_DATA_SET = "fraud_predictions"
TIMESTAMP = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
DESTINATION_DATA_SET = "{prefix}_{timestamp}".format(
    prefix=DESTINATION_DATA_SET, timestamp=TIMESTAMP
)

## Output table. Make sure that the table does NOT already exist; 
## the BatchReadFeatureValues API cannot overwrite an existing table
DESTINATION_TABLE_NAME = "training_data"

DESTINATION_PATTERN = "bq://{project}.{dataset}.{table}"
DESTINATION_TABLE_URI = DESTINATION_PATTERN.format(
    project=PROJECT_ID, dataset=DESTINATION_DATA_SET, 
    table=DESTINATION_TABLE_NAME
)

## Create dataset
client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT_ID)
dataset_id = "{}.{}".format(client.project, DESTINATION_DATA_SET)
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_id)
dataset.location = REGION
dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset)
print("Created dataset {}.{}".format(client.project, dataset.dataset_id))

## Create client for CRUD and data_client for reading feature values.
client = aiplatform.gapic.FeaturestoreServiceClient(
    client_options={"api_endpoint": API_ENDPOINT})
data_client = aiplatform.gapic.FeaturestoreOnlineServingServiceClient(
    client_options={"api_endpoint": API_ENDPOINT})
BASE_RESOURCE_PATH = client.common_location_path(PROJECT_ID, REGION)

## Create featurestore (only the first time)
create_lro = client.create_featurestore(
    featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeaturestoreRequest(
        parent=BASE_RESOURCE_PATH,
        featurestore_id=FEATURESTORE_ID,
        featurestore=featurestore_pb2.Featurestore(
            online_serving_config=featurestore_pb2.Featurestore.OnlineServingConfig(
                fixed_node_count=1
            ),
        ),
    )
)

## Wait for LRO to finish and get the LRO result.
print(create_lro.result())

client.get_featurestore(
    name=client.featurestore_path(PROJECT_ID, REGION, FEATURESTORE_ID)
)

## Create credit card entity type (only the first time)
cc_entity_type_lro = client.create_entity_type(
    featurestore_service_pb2.CreateEntityTypeRequest(
        parent=client.featurestore_path(PROJECT_ID, REGION, FEATURESTORE_ID),
        entity_type_id="creditcards",
        entity_type=entity_type_pb2.EntityType(
            description="Credit card entity",
        ),
    )
)

## Create fraud entity type (only the first time)
fraud_entity_type_lro = client.create_entity_type(
    featurestore_service_pb2.CreateEntityTypeRequest(
        parent=client.featurestore_path(PROJECT_ID, REGION, FEATURESTORE_ID),
        entity_type_id="frauds",
        entity_type=entity_type_pb2.EntityType(
            description="Fraud entity",
        ),
    )
)

## Create features for credit card type (only the first time)
client.batch_create_features(
    parent=client.entity_type_path(PROJECT_ID, REGION, FEATURESTORE_ID, "creditcards"),
    requests=[
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v1",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v2",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v3",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v4",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v5",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v6",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v7",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v8",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v9",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v10",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v11",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v12",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v13",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v14",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v15",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v16",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v17",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v18",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v19",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v20",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v21",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v22",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v23",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v24",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v25",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v26",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v27",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="v28",
        ),
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="amount",
        ),
    ],
).result()

## Create features for fraud type (only the first time)
client.batch_create_features(
    parent=client.entity_type_path(PROJECT_ID, REGION, FEATURESTORE_ID, "frauds"),
    requests=[
        featurestore_service_pb2.CreateFeatureRequest(
            feature=feature_pb2.Feature(
                value_type=feature_pb2.Feature.ValueType.DOUBLE, description="",
            ),
            feature_id="class",
        ),
    ],
).result()

## Import features values for credit cards
import_cc_request = aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest(
    entity_type=client.entity_type_path(
        PROJECT_ID, REGION, FEATURESTORE_ID, "creditcards"),
    csv_source=aiplatform.gapic.CsvSource(gcs_source=aiplatform.gapic.GcsSource(
        uris=["gs://fraud-detection-19102021/dataset/cc_details_train.csv"])),
    entity_id_field="cc_id",
    feature_specs=[
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v1"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v2"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v3"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v4"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v5"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v6"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v7"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v8"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v9"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v10"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v11"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v12"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v13"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v14"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v15"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v16"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v17"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v18"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v19"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v20"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v21"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v22"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v23"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v24"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v25"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v26"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v27"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="v28"),
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="amount"),
    ],
    feature_time_field='time',
    worker_count=1,
)

## Start to import
ingestion_lro = client.import_feature_values(import_cc_request)

## Polls for the LRO status and prints when the LRO has completed
ingestion_lro.result()

## Import features values for frauds
import_fraud_request = aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest(
    entity_type=client.entity_type_path(
        PROJECT_ID, REGION, FEATURESTORE_ID, "frauds"),
    csv_source=aiplatform.gapic.CsvSource(gcs_source=aiplatform.gapic.GcsSource(
        uris=["gs://fraud-detection-19102021/dataset/data_fraud_train.csv"])),
    entity_id_field="fraud_id",
    feature_specs=[
        aiplatform.gapic.ImportFeatureValuesRequest.FeatureSpec(id="class"),
    ],
    feature_time_field='time',
    worker_count=1,
)

## Start to import
ingestion_lro = client.import_feature_values(import_fraud_request)

## Polls for the LRO status and prints when the LRO has completed
ingestion_lro.result()
```

When I check the `Ingestion Jobs` from the `Feature` section of Google Cloud Console I see that the job has finished but no values are added to my features.

Any advice it is really precious.

Thank you all.

**EDIT 1**
In the image below there is an example of the first row of the csv file I used as input (`cc_details_train.csv`). All the unseen features  are similar, the feature `class` can assume 0 or 1 values.
The injection job lasts about 5 minutes to import (ideally) 3000 rows, but it ends without error and without importing any value.

[image: Rows of my csv file]

Comment: I have some questions for it, All your fields are numbers? You set all to double value types, can you confirm?. what is the size of your processing file? (sample data use movie data) you may require to check the processing times table, [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/comparing-ml-model-predictions-using-cloud-dataflow-pipelines#results) .Also, Can you also point where exactly in the code the error points?

Comment: @Betjens thank you for your comment. 1) Yes, all the feature values I want to ingest are double type. 2) The size of my file is 3000 rows. From the "Feature" section of GCP I see that the ingestion job has been completed but  0 values are added to the features. 3) The error raises when I do ingestion_lro.result().

Comment: So I dig a bit and found that cc_details_train.csv is your actual input file... that needs to be clarify. It would help if you can also provide additional info. ie: a sample row of your input file. I think you should either work with less features or increase your worker count if possible. For my test run I just use one row and it took 10-15 mins first time.. i cant imagine how much time it will take for 3000 rows.

Comment: @Betjens in the test I've done, the injestion job lasts about 5 minutes to import (ideally) 3000 rows, but it ends without error and without importing any value. I've added an image of the first row of the csv file.

Comment: your entity_id is cc_id??? I saw that your file also contains a column named class, what it contains???. I have replicated also with 3000 rows and added 0 values. According to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting#feature-store) there is a delay each time it runs. Also, did you try using the vertex UI for it? On Vertex-AI > features

Comment: My entity ID is cc_id. the column class contains the label of the target but I do not injest it. My aim was to write the python code, but I will follow your suggest to use UI, thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer, let me know if it works on your side too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VERTEX AI recomendations when using CSV to ImportValues / using ImportFeatureValuesRequest**

Its possible that when using this feature you might end not able to import any data at all. You must pay attention to the time field you are using as it must be in compliance with google time formats.

1. feature_time_field, must follow the time constraint rule set by google which is RFC3339, ie: '2021-04-15T08:28:14Z'. You can check details about the field [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.featurestores.entityTypes/importFeatureValues#request-body) and details about timestamp format can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#timestamp).
2. Other columns, fields must match is designed value. One exception is field entity_id_field, As it can be any value.

Note: I my test i found that if i do not properly set up the time field as google recommended date format it will just not upload any feature value at all.

*test.csv*

```
cc_id,time,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15,v16,v17,v18,v19,v20,v21,v22,v23,v24,v25,v26,v27,v28,amount
100,2021-04-15T08:28:14Z,-1.359807,-0.072781,2.534897,1.872351,2.596267,0.465238,0.923123,0.347986,0.987354,1.234657,2.128645,1.958237,0.876123,-1.712984,-0.876436,1.74699,-1.645877,-0.936121,1.456327,0.087623,1.900872,2.876234,1.874123,0.923451,0.123432,0.000012,1.212121,0.010203,1000
```

*output:*

```
imported_entity_count: 1
imported_feature_value_count: 29
```

**About optimization and working with features**

You can check the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-text#single-label-classification) to see the min and max amount of records recommended for processing. As a piece of advice you should only use the actual working features to run and the recommended amount of values for it.

**See your running ingested job**

Either if you use VertexUI or code to generated the ingested job. You can track its run by going into the UI to this path:

```
VertexAI > Features > View Ingested Jobs
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Now I'm able to import feature values in my featurestore. I have one last doubt. Even if the injestion job says that all the values were imported, If I open one of my features in UI, in "Statistics" the tag "Count" is still equal to "-". Is this ok?

Comment: For what I see in the UI, it looks like its part of the features monitoring preview. Well its a ongoing implementation, I think you should enable and wait for the interval to complete and see if its actually working. As per description in the feature monitoring: "Provides descriptive statistics and distribution shapes."

Comment: Hello Marco, I just confirmed my assumption. I was able to get that info populated. FYI